# Verilog disable Statement not Working but $finish works but it is not synthesizable?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, system-verilog, hdl

I want to design an counter which counts up to some number, lets say it is 3, for this I write a code that work well with **"$finish"** but not with **"disable"**.

I want to use this counter for synthesis so I have to use "disable" statement .....

I have attached my both code-
 (1) With $finish that stops easily & accurately

```
// Code with $finish   
module counter(input wire  clk);

reg [23:0]N=24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;

always @ (posedge clk)
 begin 

  if (N == 24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011)
   begin 
    $display("Inside If N=%d in Time=",N,$time);
    $finish;
   end
   else 
   begin 
    N <= N +1;    
    $display("Inside Else N=%d in Time=",N,$time);
   end 
  end

endmodule
```

(2) With disable that not stop at all..

```
// Code with disable that not stop    
module counter(input wire  clk);

reg [23:0]N=24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;

always @ (posedge clk)
 begin :close

  if (N == 24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011)
   begin 
    $display("Inside If N=%d in Time=",N,$time);
    disable close; 
  end
  else 
  begin 
    N <= N +1;    
    $display("Inside Else N=%d in Time=",N,$time);
  end 
 end

endmodule
```

Comment: sir so according to you what is the change that I need to do......I mean can you briefly describe it by giving some code...

Answer (score 0):

Put the `$finish` at the end of your test bench, not in your synthetically RTL.

`$finish` stops all running processes and ends the simulation. `disable` stops one process and its child processes. In your sample code, `disable close` terminates the code within the always block, it does not stop the clock. The next positive edge clock and the always block will try to run again.

See [IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 20.2 for the `$finish` statement and § 9.6.2 for the Disable statement

Comment: Greg sir but in actual hardware how can I stop a clock that nothing but a clock of FPGA ......I mean as you describe that I have to disable top level module and not the design unit ...

Comment: Look at the clock generator module definition. There is usually a input port for enabling/disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

toolic and Greg have both indicated to incorrect uses of $finish and disable, this is just to add to both of those points and show a possible solution, seperating test from synthesizable RTL.

```
module counter(input clk);

  reg [23:0] N = 24'b0;

  always @ (posedge clk) begin 
    if (N < 24'd3) begin 
      N <= N +1; 
      $display("Inside If N=%d in Time=",N,$time);
    end
    else begin 
      $display("Inside Else N=%d in Time=",N,$time);
    end 
  end
endmodule
```

To test it:

```
module test;

//Create clk
reg clk;
initial begin
  clk = 0 ;
  forever begin
    #5  clk =   ~clk;
  end
end

//instantiate DUT (Device Under Test)
counter counter_i0(
  .clk( clk )
);

// The test
//  Run for 6 clock cycles then end
initial begin
  repeat (6) begin
    @(posedge clk)
  end
  $finish;
end
endmodule
```

If you mean to stop at count 3, I would use decimal notation 24'd3 for the constant, as it gives clear intent.

also if using `==` to stop a counter a glitch could cause this to be missed and you have to wait for this to wrap arround. Or using a less than comparator means that the count target can be adjusted on the fly with out fear of skipping the exact value in `==` and having to wait a really long time for it to wrap around.

inputs are implicitly wires, no need to define them as such but you can if you want.